# How do I programatically raise an existing event within a custom control?

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I have made a custom class by inheriting a DateTimePicker and made some methods that allow it to be blank/null.

If the control is blank and a user clicks on it, it populates with the current date. It also raises the `ValueChanged` event.

If the control is populated and a user presses delete, it clears and sets its value to null, but the `ValueChanged` event *doesn't trigger.*

In the control's `OnKeyDown` method, I would like to include some code that raises the `ValueChanged` event, but there doesn't seem to be a way to do that.

Do I need to override the base class event? Is there an applicable example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DateTimePicker.OnValueChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.onvaluechanged.aspx) will raise the ValueChanged event.

Comment: This seems to work: `base.OnValueChanged(new EventArgs());` - though I am not sure whether the event arguments should be anything in particular.

Comment: @JYelton: You can use EventArgs.Empty to avoid creating a new object.  The ValueChanged event doesn't pass any information in its EventArgs, so it doesn't matter what object you provide.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call/override `DateTimePicker.OnValueChanged()`. This method calls the event, so you can implement your code through this.